# Apply function n items at a time along axis

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I am looking for a way to apply a function n items at the time along an axis. E.g.

```
array([[ 1,  2], 
       [ 3,  4],
       [ 5,  6],
       [ 7,  8]])
```

If I apply `sum` across the rows 2 items at a time I get:

```
array([[  4,   6], 
       [ 12,  14]])
```

Which is the `sum` of 1st 2 rows and the last 2 rows.

NB: I am dealing with much larger array and I have to apply the function to n items which I can be decided at runtime.

---

The data extends along different axis. E.g.

```
array([[... [ 1,  2, ...], 
            [ 3,  4, ...],
            [ 5,  6, ...],
            [ 7,  8, ...],
            ...], ...])
```

Comment: Larger in multiple dimensions.

Comment: Maybe you can add an example of a such a case.

Comment: Added an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a reduction:

```
numpy.add.reduceat(a, [0,2])
>>> array([[ 4,  6],
           [12, 14]], dtype=int32)
```

As long as by "larger" you mean longer in the "y" axis, you can extend:

```
a = numpy.array([[ 1,  2],
                 [ 3,  4],
                 [ 5,  6],
                 [ 7,  8],
                 [ 9, 10],
                 [11, 12]])
numpy.add.reduceat(a, [0,2,4])
>>> array([[ 4,  6],
           [12, 14],
           [20, 22]], dtype=int32)
```

EDIT: actually, this works fine for "larger in both dimensions", too:

```
a = numpy.arange(24).reshape(6,4)
numpy.add.reduceat(a, [0,2,4])
>>> array([[ 4,  6,  8, 10],
           [20, 22, 24, 26],
           [36, 38, 40, 42]], dtype=int32)
```

I will leave it up to you to adapt the indices to your specific case.

Comment: One thing I could not figure out what `[0,2,4]` is. What is the meaning of the last `4`?

Comment: In the first axis (y) direction, it represents the "start" of the range for add. For example: 0:2, 2:4, 4:end. In the last example: `a[4:,:]`  gives `array([[16, 17, 18, 19], [20, 21, 22, 23]])`.

Answer (score 2):

Reshape splitting the first axis into two axes, such that the second split axis is of length `n` to have a 3D array and then sum along that split axis, like so -

```
a.reshape(a.shape[0]//n,n,a.shape[1]).sum(1)
```

It should be pretty efficient as reshaping just creates a view into input array.

Sample run -

```
In [55]: a
Out[55]: 
array([[2, 8, 0, 0],
       [1, 5, 3, 3],
       [6, 1, 4, 7],
       [0, 4, 0, 7],
       [8, 0, 8, 1],
       [8, 3, 3, 8]])

In [56]: n = 2 # Sum every two rows

In [57]: a.reshape(a.shape[0]//n,n,a.shape[1]).sum(1)
Out[57]: 
array([[ 3, 13,  3,  3],
       [ 6,  5,  4, 14],
       [16,  3, 11,  9]])
```

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

```
n = 2
# calculate the cumsum along axis 0 and take one row from every n rows
cumarr = arr.cumsum(axis = 0)[(n-1)::n]                

# calculate the difference of the resulting numpy array along axis 0   
np.vstack((cumarr[0][None, :], np.diff(cumarr, axis=0)))

# array([[ 4,  6],
#        [12, 14]])
```